# Is there a way to lower vassal integration cost?

Tags: stellaris

I just received a somewhat large vassal after defeating them in a war with my alliance. Now when I check the subject integration it says it costs 1105 influence but the absolute maximum I can ever reach is 1k ... is there a way to lower the integration cost or will I never be able to integrate them (in a non game modifying way)?

Comment: Declare war on his neighbor but don't come to his aid at first. Anything that makes the power gap between you and your vassal larger, should work.

Comment: That won't work in this case as that vassal has no border friction with anyone other than my empire and one of my alliance's member's. Besides, his fleet was completely destroyed by me and another war will reduce neither his naval capacity (I destroyed pretty much any of his space ports) nor his technology research. They're absolutely not powerful anymore, it's just that they have occupied quite some space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is bit of misunderstanding in your sentence:

> Integration it says it costs 1105 influence but the absolute maximum I can ever reach is 1k

The integration cost can go well over 1k and indeed the maximum **accumulated** influence limit is just 1000, but you pay for integration on monthly basis -5 points per month until you'll pay it all, not a total number all at once. So it is not as hard to offset that cost [by other means](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/265559/how-to-increase-influence-in-stellaris) like declaring rivalries,  gaining support from factions, completing your ruler's mandate etc.

I was going to write here about the Vassal Acculturation, but [according to wiki](http://www.stellariswiki.com/Traditions#Domination) it has been changed - instead of reducing the integration cost by 33% now it provides Unity bonus:

[image]

Comment: You're right. I had assumed you needed the accumulated influence in order to start vassal integration, wich was a misinterpretation on my side. Yes, they changed the effect of Vassal Acculturation in 1.8. I will mark your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The tradition Vassal Acculturation in the Domination tree causes the vassal integration cost to drop by 33%. In this case from 1105 to ca. 737, which is a reachable amount.

Comment: You might want to reword this if possible.  It's giving off a comment vibe.

Comment: I could be more accurate but other than that I'm not sure what you actually mean. I'd actually have added this as comment but I wanted to solve the question.

Comment: It's not that it's inaccurate, it's just that it's worded in a forum like manner.  It be more appropriate if you worded it as if you weren't the one asking the question.  Here on Arqade, we take format into strong consideration when reviewing posts.  Basically, I'm just trying to help you out for any future answers you may post here ☺

Comment: You could improve this answer by stating which tradition in which tree gives that benefit.

Comment: @TimmyJim & Philipp I changed my answer, thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

The influence cost doesn't really mean much as you still gain influence.

It's very difficult to actually reach zero from 1k unless you have -7 influence gain for over 100 months which integration generally is but the influence cost is maxed out at -5 per month until the cost is reached.